# How do non-dimorphic birds distinguish sex of possible partners/rivals?

Tags: ornithology, sexual-dimorphism

Some birds, such as my pet [*Pionus chalcopterus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bronze-winged_parrot), are not sexually dimorphic.  People can't tell them apart, and even trained avian vets are not 100% certain with an inspection probing the vent.

I understand that when not "in season" there is no physical difference as internal sex organs are atrophied to save weight.

But how do *they* tell the difference?

Do they have dimorphic markings that bird eyes (but not humans eyes) can see?

Comment: Since we're not birds there's no way of knowing for sure, but I would imagine calls/songs and possibly pheromones have something to do with it. There may also be anatomical differences as well that humans haven't discovered yet.

Comment: Behavioral differences are likely a part of it, at least for some species.

Answer (score 2):

As very well explained also in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection_in_birds , visual signaling is only one of the way birds uses to pick a partner, olfactory and acoustic signals also play a major role.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I would still like to know about Pionus specifically though.

Comment: I can't find anything about Pionus specifically, but I don't see why it should be different.